# Only the first value is added to the DB and not the rest

Tags: php, html

The value Category is added to the database with the insert query. No other value is added to the table.
Here's my PHP:

```
 <?php
         $date="";
         $category="";
         $item="";
         $vendor="";
         $issue_morn=0.0;
         $issue_noon=0.0;
         $issue_night=0.0;
         $wastage=0.0;
         $receipt=0.0;
         $open_stock=0.0;
         $close_stock=0.0;
         $monthly_open_stock=0.0;
         $monthly_close_stock=0.0;
         $unit="";
         $sth = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO annapoorna.inventory 
             (`date`, category, item, vendor, unit, open_stock, close_stock, recipt,
     issue_morn, issue_noon, issue_night, wastage, monthly_open_stock, monthly_close_stock) 
     VALUES  (:date, :category, :item, :vendor, :unit, :open_stock, :close_stock,:recipt, :issue_morn, :issue_noon, 
             :issue_night, :wastage, :monthly_open_stock, :monthly_close_stock)');
         if(!empty($_POST['datepicker']))
         {
           $date=$_POST['datepicker'];
         }
         if(!empty($_POST['category']))
         {
         $category=$_POST['category'];
         }
        if(!empty($_POST['item']))
         {
         $item=$_POST['item'];
         }
        if(!empty($_POST['vendor']))
         {
         $vendor=$_POST['vendor'];
         }

         $sth->execute(array(':date'=>$date, ':category'=>$category, ':item'=>$item, ':vendor'=>$vendor, 
             ':unit'=>$unit, ':open_stock'=>$open_stock,':close_stock'=>$close_stock,':recipt'=>$receipt, 
             ':issue_morn'=>$issue_morn, ':issue_noon'=>$issue_noon, ':issue_night'=>$issue_noon, 
             ':wastage'=>$wastage, ':monthly_open_stock'=>$monthly_open_stock, 
             ':monthly_close_stock'=>$monthly_close_stock));


         ?>
```

Here's my HTML (and some PHP in it to fetch data from DB for drop down):

```
<form name="form" method="POST" style="display:inline;">
            <select name="category" id="category" value="category" class="form-control ddplaceholder" style="width:220px;font-size:18px;font-family:Roboto;"  onchange="document.form.submit();">
                 <option value="" disabled selected>Select Category</option>
            <?php
            $sth = $conn->prepare('Select name From category');
            $sth->execute();
            $data = $sth->fetchAll();   
            foreach ($data as $row ){
                if($row['name']!="")
             echo ' <option id=\"CategoryName\" nameCategoryNameVendorName\" value="' .$row['name']. '">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
            }
            ?> 
            </select>

            <select name="item_name_update" value="item_name_update" class="form-control ddplaceholder" style="width:220px; padding-left:40px;font-size:18px;font-family:Roboto;"  onchange="document.form.submit();">
                   <option value="" disabled selected>Select Item</option>
            <?php
            $sth = $conn->prepare('Select item_name From item');
            $sth->execute();
            $data = $sth->fetchAll();   
            foreach ($data as $row ){
                if($row['item_name']!="")
             echo ' <option id=\"ItemName\" name=\"ItemName\" value="' .$row['item_name']. '">'.$row['item_name'].'</option>';
            }
            ?> </select>
            <select name="vendor_name_update" value="vendor_name_update" class="form-control ddplaceholder" style="width:220px; padding-left:40px;font-size:18px;font-family:Roboto;"  onchange="document.form.submit();">
                   <option value="" disabled selected>Select Vendor</option>

            <?php
            $sth = $conn->prepare('Select name From vendor');
            $sth->execute();
            $data = $sth->fetchAll();   
            foreach ($data as $row ){
                if($row['name']!="")
             echo ' <option id=\"VendorName\" name=\"VendorName\" value="' .$row['name']. '">'.$row['name'].'</option>';
            }
            ?> 
            </select>
         </br>
           Monthly Op Stock<input type="text" placeholder="Monthly op Stock"</>
           Current Op Stock<input type="text" placeholder="Current op Stock"</>

           <p>

           <input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='EditItemList.php'" value="Edit Item List"/>
           <input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='EditVendorList.php'" value="Edit Vendor List"/>
           </p>
         <hr>

<table class="inventory" style="float:left">
  <tr>
    <td>Unit</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Unit"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Opening Stock</td>
      <td>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Opening stock"/>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Closing Stock</td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Closing ctock"/>
  </td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Receipt</td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Receipt"/>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>



<table class="inventory2">
<tr>
      <td>Issue Morning</td>
      <td>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Issue Morning"/>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Issue Noon</td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Issue Noon"/>
  </td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Issue Night</td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Issue Night"/>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Wastage</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Wastage"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
                   </form>
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: missing `name` attribute in form field?

Comment: So name attribute is assigned for 'vendor' value but even then it's not being added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify a name attribute.

Without the name attribute, it's impossible for the browser to send anything. So here's example:

```
<input type="text" name="open_stock" placeholder="Opening stock"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Attribute name is missing in your input tags.

name="my-field" in the frontend will give you $_POST['my-field'] in the backend